# Convert a two dimensional array(length 9) to a Grids of 3 x 3 (9 elements)

Tags: python, matrix, iteration, spatial

I have a 2-D array which represent a series of row values in a table shown below:

```
[
  ["5","3",".",".","7",".",".",".","."],
  ["6",".",".","1","9","5",".",".","."],
  [".","9","8",".",".",".",".","6","."],
  ["8",".",".",".","6",".",".",".","3"],
  ["4",".",".","8",".","3",".",".","1"],
  ["7",".",".",".","2",".",".",".","6"],
  [".","6",".",".",".",".","2","8","."],
  [".",".",".","4","1","9",".",".","5"],
  [".",".",".",".","8",".",".","7","9"]
]
```

I needed to get column values from the same and I was able to do that using

```
map(list, zip(*arr))
and got this:

[
 ['5', '6', '.', '8', '4', '7', '.', '.', '.'], 
 ['3', '.', '9', '.', '.', '.', '6', '.', '.'], 
 ['.', '.', '8', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
 ['.', '1', '.', '.', '8', '.', '.', '4', '.'], 
 ['7', '9', '.', '6', '.', '2', '.', '1', '8'], 
 ['.', '5', '.', '.', '3', '.', '.', '9', '.'], 
 ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '2', '.', '.'], 
 ['.', '.', '6', '.', '.', '.', '8', '.', '7'], 
 ['.', '.', '.', '3', '1', '6', '.', '5', '9']
]
```

Now I need to create a similar two dimensional array that contains 3 x 3 grid elements and the output should look like below

```
[
 ['5','3','.','6','.','.','.','9','8'],
 ['.','7','.','1','9','5','.','.','.'],
 ['.','.','.','.','.','.','.','6','.'],
 ['8','.','.','4','.','.','7','.','.'],
 ['.','6','.','8','.','3','.','2','.'],
 ['.','.','3','.','.','1','.','.','6'],
 ['.','6','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
 ['.','.','.','4','1','9','.','8','.'],
 ['2','8','.','.','.','5','.','7','9']
]
```

I tried to zip 3 elements together and iterate 3 rows but I got nothing

```
x = 3
for i in range(x):
  map(list, zip(*arr)[0,1,2])
  x += 3
```

Answer (score 0):

For a nested-for-loops example, anyway:

```
def get_3x3_grids(arr):
    grids = []
    for r in range(0, 9, 3):
        for c in range(0, 9, 3):
            grids_row = []
            for row in range(r, r + 3):
                grids_row += arr[row][c:c + 3]
            grids.append(grids_row)

    return grids
```